# How to mock a non-class, non-exported variable without testbed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a larger number of services I need to test. Class test, not component test, thus I can not use Testbed, but have to mock it using `let service = new MyService`. But, a small number of those services use hard-coded objects that are neither class-variables, nor exported.

How can I access those variables and make them available to the constructor?

my.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ServicedItem } from '../../models/serviced-item.model';

const headers = new HttpHeaders() // <--- How to mock this???
.append('appended stuff here');

export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject('env') private env,
  ) {}

  public getServicedItem(id: string): Observable<ServicedItem> {
    return this.httpClient.get<ServicedItem>(
      `${this.env.webApiBaseUrl}servicedItem/${id}`, 
      { headers }
    );
  }
}
```

my.service.spec.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

jest.mock('@angular/common/http');

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  const webApiBaseUrl: string = 'mocky-yeah'
  const env = { 'webApiBaseUrl': webApiBaseUrl } as any;
  const id: string = 'THE_id';
  const testPayload: string = 'Insert correct string here';

  describe('CLASS: mocked backend tests', () => {
    const httpClient: any = { get: jest.fn() };

    beforeEach(() => {
      service = new MyService(httpClient, env);
    });

    test('should be created', () => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('METHOD: getServicedItem', () => {
      test('should return servicedItem', (done) => {
        httpClient.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => of(testPayload));
        service.getServicedItem().subscribe((res) => {
          expect(httpClient.get).toBeCalledWith(`${webApiBaseUrl}servicedItem/${id}`);
          expect(res).toBe(testPayload);
          done();
        }, done.fail)
      });
    });

  });
```

As is, I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined on the headers. I've searched for ways to do this for ... lets say far to long already. But all tutorials I find either assume Testbed, or go for class or at least exported variables. But there has to be a way to do this, right?

and the error thrown:

```
● Test suite failed to run 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined 

4 | import { ServicedItem } from '../../models/serviced-item.model'; 
5 | > 
6 | const headers = new HttpHeaders() 
  |                  ^ 
7 | .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

EDIT:

adding the precise error block after some input.

Comment: *Don't* mock it - it's part of the implementation, test that the right request gets made.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't it's not even constructing the service. Everything screams it's either a very stupid typo or such again (believe me I checked again, again and again for that), or some weird stuff that has little to do with the test itself. I just can't find a start to unravel that thing.

Comment: From the error it looks like there's an errant pipe `|` at the end of line 6, make sure you're giving a [mre] that actually recreates the issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry that pipe is from copying from the terminal.

Comment: Because you've mocked out the whole of `@angular/common/http`, there isn't a working implementation of `HttpHeaders`. *"Class test, not component test, thus I can not use Testbed"* - you can still use the TestBed to test service classes like this, see e.g. https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests.

Comment: Thank you a lot @jonrsharpe. You helped a lot. 
I just don't get, what you mean by being able to test the class only while using testbed. Isn't that what testbed does: starting a testing ngmodule, handling all the overhead, safely tearing it down... and thereby test the whole component?
The reason why I want to avoid testbed is not, that it does a bad job. It does a good job, but to do so, has quite a bit of work to do. Resulting in a base cost of ~200ms per test.

Which is not problem with 40 tests, but quickly starts to add up when you want to have x00 tests in your CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is caused by

```js
jest.mock('@angular/common/http');
```

in the test. Try to remove it, or to mock its exports properly.

```js
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { MyService } from './my.service';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  const webApiBaseUrl = 'mocky-yeah';
  const env = {webApiBaseUrl} as any;
  const id = 'THE_id';
  const testPayload = 'Insert correct string here';

  describe('CLASS: mocked backend tests', () => {
    const httpClient: any = {get: jest.fn()};

    beforeEach(() => {
      service = new MyService(httpClient, env);
    });

    test('should be created', () => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('METHOD: getServicedItem', () => {
      test('should return servicedItem', async () => {
        httpClient.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => of(testPayload));
        const res = await service.getServicedItem(id).toPromise();
        expect(httpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          `${webApiBaseUrl}servicedItem/${id}`,
          {
            headers: jasmine.any(HttpHeaders),
          },
        );
        expect(res).toBe(testPayload);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const headers = new HttpHeaders() // <--- How to mock this???
  .append('Foo', 'Bar');

export class MyService {
  public constructor(
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject('env') private env,
  ) {}

  public getServicedItem(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(
      `${this.env.webApiBaseUrl}servicedItem/${id}`,
      { headers },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem isn't the assertion. The problem is, that the test can't be run at all, as the service isn't properly constructed without access to the header.

Comment: The service has access to the `headers` because they are in the same scope. At least it is intented like that :) Can you double check that the line where the error has been caused belongs to `.append('appended stuff here')`?

Comment: ```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined

      4 | import { ServicedItem } from '../../models/serviced-item.model';
      5 | 
    > 6 | const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        |                 ^
      7 |   .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      8 |   .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
      9 |   .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
```
That's where it fails. Somehow that headers is undefined, that's why I asked how to access it.

Comment: Hm... very interesting... do you use https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks ? It sounds like the imports have been mocked already. I'll try to play with your code later today. With Angular version do you use?

Comment: "@angular-devkit/core": "10.0.4", the mock is a ts-jest (^25.0.0) mocked. I'll have to look into your link, once I'm home. Yay, walking through the snow. ;)

Comment: please check the answer, looks like `jest.mock('@angular/common/http');` is the cause of the problem.